# Many to many Laravel 5.3 is not overriding column name for a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this tables:

[image]

And I have this models:

```
Video 
Category
```

I'm trying to query a many to many relation to get all videos that belongs to one specific category.

I have a route `domain.dev/category/{category}` that points to my `CategoryController` and his respective view. I'm receiving it through `$request`.

I tried to fetch the data from models in the controller (echoing with php) and passing the variable to the view and doing:

```
@foreach ($category->videos as $video) {
    {{ $video->title }}
}
@endforeach
```

But when Laravel executes the query it throws an exception, and it shows the query:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 769:
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'videos.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `videos`.*, `videos_categories`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `videos_categories`.`video_id` as `pivot_video_id` from `videos` inner join `videos_categories` on `videos`.`id` = `videos_categories`.`video_id` where `videos_categories`.`category_id` is null)
```

It looks like the `videos.id` column, was not overriden (since I have NO `id` field in `videos`, I used `videos_id` as you can see in the migrations, and in the models. I've explicitly overriden the keys in the models, also in the relations.

I didn't knew that was a common practice to use alphabetical order for the pivot tables... And my pivot table is `videos_categories` and not `categories_videos` as it should "by convention", so I also overriden the table names in the relations.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or why laravel its using `videos`.`id`
So I need some help. I also tried searching for other Q/A before writing my own but I didn't found any solution.

Here's the CategoryController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Shows the Category page
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $category = Category::where('category', $request->category)->first();
        // THINGS I TRIED
        /*
        $videos = $category->videos()->get();

        foreach ($category->videos as $video) {
            echo $video->title;
        }
        */

        return view('category.index', ['category' => $category]);
    }
}
```

---

Migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateVideosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('video_id')->unique();
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->string('embed_code', 255);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('videos');
    }
}

<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('category_id')->unique();
            $table->string('category', 45);
            $table->string('thumbnail');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

Migrations for pivot tables

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateVideosCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('videos_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->integer('video_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->foreign('video_id')
                ->references('video_id')
                ->on('videos')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('category_id')
                ->references('category_id')
                ->on('categories')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('videos_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['video_id', 'category_id']);
            $table->dropColumn('video_id');
            $table->dropColumn('category_id');
        });
        Schema::dropIfExists('videos_categories');
    }
}
```

Models

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'videos';
    protected $primarykey = 'video_id';

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'videos_categories', 'video_id', 'category_id');
    }
    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'videos_tags', 'video_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primarykey = 'category_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Video', 'videos_categories', 'category_id', 'video_id');
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property has to be `$primaryKey` and not `$primarykey` in your models.

By the way, there is a reason why the default value is `id` and not `model_id`, it is because it is a standard way of naming your columns, and I would advice not to go against such conventions without a good reason, for the reason you're facing but also because it will ease eventual collaboration with another developer.

Comment: Someone told me that was a good practice to name keys with `<name>_id` to avoid having ambiguous and multiple `id` fields from different tables in complex queries, forcing us to make a lot of alias. Made sense to me and this is what I did. In the other hand, I don't understand why should be better to just use `id`. Maybe it's not a convention outside laravel... Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Ah, and the answer is correct. It works using $primaryKey :P Thank you !!

Comment: I understand and I agree that it can be useful for this very reason, but then you should name your other fields `video_title` in case you have a `category_title` field, right? In the end, it will make everything harder to read, because if you're doing your SQL queries by hand, you can just prefix the column with the table: `videos.id` or `categories.id`. In a framework (and generally speaking in OO) it makes even less sense, because you would then access your field this way: `$video->video_id`, which is a useless repetition. That said, in the end, I believe it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Uhmmm... You're right, since prefixing solves the problem I was talking about and makes code cleaner, then easier to read. Thank you for your insights :)

Comment: By the way you can make an "abbreviation" for the table prefix: `SELECT v.id, c.id FROM videos AS v, categories AS c` if you didn't know :)

Comment: I knew it. I just haven't used SQL for so looooong. Haha And I need to get used again... Thanks